# Как компенсировать сдвиг в scrollview при изменении размера элементов?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как заставить scrollview в android компенсировать сдвиг элементов, при изменении их размера, чтобы окно не дёргалось?

Немного подробнее:

При прокручивании scrollview и последующем взаимодействии с одним из его объектов, другие объекты, находящиеся выше, могут измениться в размере, что приводит к сдвигу вверх или вниз, выбранного объекта, относительно того места, где объект находился до взаимодействия с ним.

Как устранить этот сдвиг?

Пример кода
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dh2U-4h0Avsd88wJa1WPCE5a280OY1Ag/view?usp=sharing

Видео
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L9MrU6T86gxPs__NeW6ThZcv0-ka0Z2-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это никак нельзя сделать. Элементы обязаны перерисоваться и контейнер обязан пересчитать свою высоту и проскролиться до заново высчитанной высоты.

То как вы хотите можно реализовать через `RecyclerView`. Если каждый элемент ваших данных будет отдельной ячейкой оного, то он или не будет вовсе перерисовываться, т.к. выгружен из памяти в этот момент или `RecyclerView` без скрола пересчитает свою высоту.